# Django WSGI Apache VirtualHost, returning a 404 Error

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.2.2
- Python 3.2.3
- Django 1.6.1

I followed directions at [Using mod_wsgi to Serve Applications on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/using-mod_wsgi-to-serve-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04), for setting up a WSGI for my Django on Apache. Problem is, the VirtualHost domain is now returning a confusingly weird 404 error:

```
[Mon Dec 16 19:53:49 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
```

It's confusing because... that directory *doesn't even exist*. The VirtualHost is setup in /var/www/main and the config's for it in /var/apache2/sites-available/default looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        ServerAlias coral
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dfy/code/djdev/djdev/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

I reloaded Apache after editing. That wsgi file is the one generated by Django when I started the project. I altered it to match what was needed according to the tutorial:

```
import os
import sys # added from tutorial
sys.path.append('/home/dfy/code/djdev/djdev/') # added from tutorial
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djdev.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

To me, this all looks like it should work, but Apache is lookin' for static files in a non-existent directory (/etc/apache2/htdocs). I've been Googling for hours trying to figure out what's wrong here, but haven't found the answer. On a whim I tried `chmod 777 wsgi.py`, but that didn't change anything, so I'm sure it's not a permissions problem. I really no idea what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but Apache is lookin' for static files in a non-existent directory

I'm not sure what is going on here, but I suspect your main configuration is not correct. If you do not supply a `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, Apache will look for it in the default location, which is `htdocs`.

As per the [django documentation on deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), you need to provide the following configuration for your virutal host. You chould change the paths as they apply to your setup:

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt

Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /path/to/mysite.com/static/styles/$1

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Please use the official docs which are updated with changes to specific django versions.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me fix it. I tried the official docs, but sometimes they seem to leave something out that I just can't figure out & I have to check elsewhere to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your loosing something:
In my vhost configuration I have:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
...
Alias /static/ /the/path/to/static/
<Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
</Location>
...

</virtualhost>
```

I hope it helps